# read integer from txt line

Tags: bash, variables, integer, readline

I have a txt file with 3 lines.

User$ cat file.txt

5   - an integer which needs to be used to determine the end of a loop

1    - a logical which indicates true or false for later conditioning

fold_nam - a name of a folder.

I now want to assign the 1st line into an integer, what I do so far is:

echo $(sed -n 1p file.txt) > loop_end

but when I try to work with the file  I cannot get anything

for example: when I do the following I get a blank line and not the value from the txt file

user$ echo $loop_end

I read about this in some forums here and experinment little bit and it does'nt seem the value needs to be converted (BTW, it was saved as an integer though matlab).

can use help with the right command line...tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the output to `loop_end` variable of type integer. What you did is redirecting the output to a file named `loop_end`.

```
declare -i loop_end=$(sed -n 1p file.txt)
echo $loop_end
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `read` built-in of bash will allow you to read the file contents as in the following example:

```
read loop_end < file.txt
```